# how to get contetnt of a row in a table from one php page to another page?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: first php page]
this is first php page and when user click "Click Me" option in the table he is redirected to new php page . How to retrieve the corresponding row details in the next page ?
THE CODE IS AS FOLLOWS :

```
$query="SELECT A.train_no AS AA, A.station_id AS AB,A.train_name AS MM,A.arrival AS AC, 

A.dept AS AD,B.station_id AS AE, B.arrival AS AF, B.dept AS 

AG,sc_mon,sc_tue,sc_wed,sc_thu,sc_fri,sc_sat,sc_sun

FROM TIME AS A,TIME AS B,tbl_schedule WHERE A.train_no = B.train_no AND 

B.train_no=sc_tr_num

AND A.station_id ='$f' AND B.station_id ='$t'";

$rs=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 

    {

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['AA']."</td><td>".$row['MM']."</td> <td>".$stname1."</td> 

<td>" .$row['AC'] ."</td> <td>".$row['AD'] . "</td><td>".$stname2. 

    "</td><td>".$row['AF'] . "</td><td>" .$row['AG']. "</td><td>".$row['sc_mon']."</td>

<td>".$row['sc_tue']."</td><td>".$row['sc_wed']."</td><td>".$row['sc_thu'].

    "</td><td>".$row['sc_fri']."</td><td>".$row['sc_sat']."</td><td>".$row['sc_sun']."

</td><td>"."<a href='Reservation.php'>Click Me</a></td></tr>";

    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

When Generating your link, include ID info

```
."<a href='Reservation.php?ID=".  $row['AA'] ."'>Click Me</a></td></tr>";
```

Then on the next page you can use the ID value to lookup the train.

Also why are you renaming your fields to things like AA which make your code impossible to read and understand?

Comment: echo "train number = ".$row['A.train_no'].".";  wont work . Here renaming of fields are required .

Comment: no but "train number = ".$row['train_no']."."; will work, and even if you did have to rename your fields it is very very basic that you should name them something readable such as TrainNoField rather than AA.  If you want to learn, you must be willing to do things like this.